# 403 or 301 domain pointing to our domain?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, 403-forbidden

We recently discovered that a large, publicly traded corporation purchased a domain that they have pointing to our domain. Both the corporation and the domain are completely unrelated to our type of website. Their domain is now coming up above us in search engines for our main keyword. Their listing in Google looks like our listing (our title, description, etc.) and initially what was happening is that someone would click on that link and surf our site, even though it was their domain in the browser window.

We are now using a 301 redirect. Is that okay or will that hurt us in some way?

We trying to figure out if that is the appropriate action to take, especially since we are unsure what they are attempting to accomplish.  Are they trying to steal our seo somehow, or are they maybe trying to damage our seo reputation, or are they trying to steal login information?

In attempting to research what is going on and what to do about it, I came across [the same question basically](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/27970/why-is-another-domain-resolving-to-my-ip-address)
 where using a 403 was suggested, but the question about security or motivation of the other party was never answered. Why use a 403 as opposed to a 301? What is going on here?

Comment: While there is not enough detail to answer your question directly, I thought of an answer that has some clues even though the scenario may be different: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/77788/why-are-these-sites-cloning-my-content-and-how-do-i-stop-them/77789#77789 In your case, it would help us to know the domain names to know how they are cloning your site. Is it okay to put these in a comment and let us explore the lay of the land for you? You can delete the comment or the moderator can hide the comment later for your protection.

Comment: @closetnoc "how they are cloning your site" - If it's like the linked question, then _they_ simply have an `A` record pointing to their IP address. Quite intrigued how this other domain is actually ranking _above_ the real domain, or even that _both_ domains would be returned in the SERPs considering it must be a _duplicate_?

Comment: @w3d That is one reason why I asked for the domain names. It could be that the trust metrics are not so high for the original domain- not that the domain has done anything wrong, but a cheap or lousy host is enough- trust me- to seriously downgrade a site through clustering (not clustering as in systems) through semantic relationships between sites and pages, normally related or not, on a host, IP address, address block, etc. A crappy host can really bring you down. Plus- I want to help the OP defeat the hack in a safe but efyoo way.

Comment: See also: [Somebody registered a global top level domain and pointed it to my site, should I be concerned?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/61110/somebody-registered-a-global-top-level-domain-and-pointed-it-to-my-site-should)